# Facing Error with command multiplot from coefplot package in R

Tags: r, coefplot

Is there anybody facing the same as I am when running the command `multiplot` from `R`package `coefplot`?

Even for the example:

```
data(diamonds)
model1 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut, data=diamonds)
model2 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut + color, data=diamonds)
model3 <- lm(price ~ carat + color, data=diamonds)
multiplot(model1, model2, model3)
```

I´m now getting the below error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
attempt to apply non-function
```

Any hint?

Comment: maybe inconsistencies between `coefplot` and the newest version of `ggplot` - I had trouble even installing `coefplot` with `ggplot2` version 2.0.0 installed ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a bit tangential, but I have found the slightly more recent combination of the `broom` and `dotwhisker` packages to be useful - `broom` is the back end (converting models to "tidy" data frames of coefficients) and `dotwhisker` is the front end (creating plots via a fairly thin `ggplot2` layer)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)
```

**update**: re-installed `dotwhisker` v 0.2.0.3, this appears to work:

```
dwplot(list(model1,model2,model3))
```

You can also `dwplot(list(m1=model1,m2=model2,m3=model3))` if you want to pick different model names on the fly.

Alternatively, for finer control you can construct the full data frame yourself:

```
mList <- list(carat_cut=model1, carat_cut_color=model2,
              carat_color=model3)
library(plyr)
## extract tidy data frames and combine them ...
mFrame <- ldply(mList,tidy,conf.int=TRUE,.id="model")
```

Now you can just do

```
dwplot(mFrame)
```